# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in IIS server 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, iis

I have looked at some of questions regarding "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" but could not get answer. Here is my issue. I have code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dr[3].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy tt h:m:s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat).ToString("MMM. dd yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

It works fine in localhost but having issues in IIS server. 
Eg. date in my Sql Server 2008 R2 is "2014-03-05 09:10:17.040"
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about: the string you use must match the string you have? "dd-MM-yyyy tt h:m:s" is not matching  "2014-03-05 09:10:17.040" - obviously, or?

Comment: Changed this to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff but still does not work this time even in localhost

Comment: Sorry to ask, why what the heck are you doing there in general? A DateTime in SQL Server is transmitted to the client as DateTime. dr[3] should already contain a DateTime struct - so ToString followe by ParseExact are two (expensive) operations that are totally useless to start with because they do exactly nothing - esxcept introducing an error. If that is a date/time field on teh server, no conversion is necessary.

Comment: While debugging i get format as 17-03-2014 PM 2:53:04 so i want to convert to custom format

Comment: Again, you likely get NO FORMAT AT ALL - if the item is a DateTime struct, then the format is just a visualization. THat is C# 101 for beginners. There is zero need to go to string then back to DateTime in a DataReader.

Comment: But can you explain what is issue that i am getting error only in IIS

Comment: No, I can not do beginner baseline debugging from my computer to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom format is wrong. If you use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, your format and string should match exactly.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

Since your string starts with year, you need use `yyyy` format first. I assume your `03` is month and `05` is day. [`h` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier) is for `1` to `12`. Since your hour is `09`, you should use [`HH` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) which is for `00` to `23`.

[`m` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mSpecifier) is ok for this string but is `0` to `59`. You might need use [`mm` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) which is for `00` to `59`. Same situation on your second part.

Also you need [`fff` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#fffSpecifier) for your milliseconds part.

As a result, you should use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` format instead.

For example;

```
string s = "2014-03-05 09:10:17.040";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                               "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
3/5/2014 9:10:17 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/4kcRrY)</kbd>.

After you parse your string, you can format is whatever you want with [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
date.ToString("MMM. dd yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

> While debugging in asp.net i get format for dr as 17-03-2014 PM
>   2:53:04

But this doesn't have a same format with example date you write in your question! Anyway, for this case, you can use `dd-MM-yyyy tt h:mm:ss` format.

For example;

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("17-03-2014 PM 2:53:04",
                               "dd-MM-yyyy tt h:mm:ss",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Unfortunately, looks like your dates don't have a standart date format each others in your database. In this such a case, it is impossible to parsing them all in a one format.

Only you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can use more than one format in a string array for your strings.

Comment: Changed this to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff but still does not work this time even in localhost

Comment: @MiteshVora What is your input on your case? Is it still `2014-03-05 09:10:17.040` format? What do you mean by doesn't work? Any exception or error message?

Comment: While debugging in asp.net i get format for dr as 17-03-2014 PM 2:53:04

Comment: @MiteshVora Updated my answer. You should use `dd-MM-yyyy tt h:mm:ss` format on this case I believe.

Comment: @MiteshVora Updated my question. Looks like your dates don't have a standart date format each others in your database.

Comment: Thanks..for your help looks like my pc has format as dd-mm-yyyy tt hh:mm so i think you could be correct..

Answer (score 0):

You're using ParseExact which will ONLY work if the format of what you're parsing matches the format of the string.

In your code you're expecting `"dd-MM-yyyy tt h:m:s"`

In the example you gave ("2014-03-05 09:10:17.040"), it's in

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Try changing it to `DateTime.Parse()` and let it determine the format itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dr[3].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat).
  ToString("MMM.dd yyyy hh:mm tt")
```